# Separate iterators in Python without iterating through them

Tags: python, iterator

I have a function that does something like this:

```
def function_a(x_iter: Iterator[dict]):
    y = {}
    for x in x_iter:
        x = other_func_1(x)
        y = other_func_2(x)
        yield x, y
```

Downstream in the process, I want to use `x` and `y` separately, e.g. I want to pass `x` as an iterator to another function and I want to save `y` to JSON file. I know we can't call it like this

```
x, y = function_a(x_iter)
```

because x and y will be in the same iterator. How should I separate them? I don't think I can do

```
result = function_a(x_iter)
for x, y in result:
    <do something with x>
    <do something with y>
```

since `x` needs to be passed to another function downstream as an iterator.

Thank you

Comment: So, I'm confused. Have you tried your code or not? If you tried some code, then please update your question with this code and the results and a comment about whether it works for you.

Comment: Maybe it's related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46941719/

Comment: So, I've tried your code (suitably modified) and it seems to work fine. However, without some concrete code from you its impossible to tell exactly what is not working.

Comment: @quamrana: I don't know what you tried, but `x, y = function_a(x_iter)` [definitely doesn't work](https://ideone.com/EqDqlD). As for the `for` loop, it's impossible to write the code like that because the iterators need to be processed by downstream functions that take iterators; the questioner cannot write an element-by-element loop.

Comment: The question is pretty clear, as is the reason why `x, y = function_a(x_iter)` doesn't work - `function_a` returns an iterator of 2-element tuples, not a tuple of two iterators. The questioner is trying to convert their iterator of 2-element tuples to two separate iterators over the first and second elements of the tuples.

Comment: yup @user2357112. Is there a way to return 2 separate iterators instead? I was thinking to run `x = other_func_1(x)` and `y = other_func_2(x)` on separate functions, but that means that I have to iterate over `x_iter` twice and that is ineffective.

Comment: @eng2019: Not a good way.

Comment: @user2357112: yes, in the same way that we don't know what the OP has tried.

Comment: @quamrana: We can see the obviously non-working code in the question. It's easy to tell it won't work, without running it. The questioner knew it wouldn't work. Seeing the ValueError doesn't really add anything.

Comment: Couldn't you simply use:
`def function_a(x_iter):x, y = itertools.tee(x_iter, 2);return map(func1, x), map(func2, y)`

Comment: @SayandipDutta: In a use case like the one in the question, that will result in fully materializing the contents of `x_iter` in the tee's underlying storage. It's less efficient than just making a list out of `x_iter`.

Comment: `itertools.tee` only pays off if the tee iterators stay positioned close to each other in the data stream. It doesn't help in use cases where one iterator will be fully consumed before the other.

Comment: @user2357112 Yeah, understood what you meant. The OP is aiming for sequential operation.  Saving a copy seems like best bet.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't rewrite the consumer functions, you're going to have to do at least 1 of the following 3 things:

- Run the downstream functions simultaneously in 2 separate threads.
- Fully materialize at least one of the data streams involved - maybe save the `y` elements to a list while you iterate over the `x` elements, or vice versa, or materialize the underling `x_iter` to a list so you can make two passes to generate the `x` and `y` elements.
- Generate the input iterator twice.

(If you're really going to save the `y` elements to a JSON file, you're probably materializing that data to a list anyway, unless you're using a streaming JSON serializer, but it sounds like the JSON thing is just an example.)

---

Say you iterate over all the `x` elements somehow. The whole time you're doing that, `function_a` is producing `y` elements. You could try to use those elements as `function_a` produces them, but if you want to do that while the downstream function that consumes the `x` elements is running, you'll have to run the `y` consumer at the same time, and the only way to do that without rewriting the consumer functions is to run them in two separate threads. That's the threads option.

If you don't use the `y` elements immediately, you can store them, but if you're not using separate threads, the `y` consumer will have to wait until the `x` consumer finishes. That means you'll have to store the entire `y` data stream, probably to a list.

If you don't use the `y` elements immediately, and you don't store them, then they're gone. You can't pull them out of nothing when you're done with the `x` elements. You have to generate them again, which means you'll need the elements of `x_iter`, but those elements are gone too. You'll need to either recreate `x_iter`, or store its contents up front (probably to a list). If you go that way, you probably wouldn't have `function_a` generate both `x` and `y` elements - you'd probably write one function that generates the `x` elements and one that generates the `y` elements, so you don't waste time doing work you don't need.

---

Note that `itertools.tee` doesn't let you get out of this. It has to store elements in memory too. `itertools.tee` only pays off in cases where the tee iterators will stay positioned close to each other in the data stream. It's worse than `list` if you're going to iterate over one iterator fully before starting on the other.

Comment: Although it is impossible to tell without knowing what functions OP intends to use the iterators in, I think you could add generator coroutines as another way to solve this. i.e. OP's `function_a` sends (`gen.send`) x, and y values into corresponding functions.

Comment: @SayandipDutta: If you mean rewriting the consumer functions as generator-based coroutines, I don't think the questioner can rewrite the consumers.

Comment: I see. Nevermind then :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, because your iterator inherently produces a tuple of 2 values. What you can do, is to make a wrapper that ignores one of them and yields only 1st value.

```
other_func_1 = lambda x: x*2
other_func_2 = lambda x: x*3

def function_a(x_iter):
    for x in x_iter:
        x1 = other_func_1(x)
        x2 = other_func_2(x)
        yield x1, x2

def take_ith(x_iter, i):
    for x in x_iter:
        yield x[i]
        
print(list(function_a(range(10))))
print(list(take_ith(function_a(range(10)), 0)))
```

If you need to generate values of `x` and `y` separately, it probably means they shouldn't be grouped in the generator in the first place.

Comment: Do you have an idea not to group them? I was thinking to run `x = other_func_1(x)` and `y = other_func_2(x)` on separate functions, but that means that I have to iterate over `x_iter` twice and that is ineffective.

Comment: @eng2019 It's hard to tell the best solution without seeing the whole code, but can't you save `y` further in the code, when the values of `x` are actually used?